# How can I jump to another line of a python code while the previous line is still running

Tags: python, django, command-line, autorun

I am trying to create a python script to auto-run all my Django commands,
but the script execution stops at  `os.system('python manage.py runserver')` and does not run the next line because `os.system('python manage.py runserver')` needs to keep running. How do I run the next line of code while `os.system('python manage.py runserver')` is still running?

I tried using the python sleep method to wait a few seconds and then run the next line, but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```
import os, webbrowser, time
os.system('pipenv shell')
os.system('python manage.py runserver')
time.sleep(5)
webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000', new=1, autoraise=True)
```

The execution stops at `os.system('python manage.py runserver')` but I want it to run `webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000', new=1, autoraise=True)` while `os.system('python manage.py runserver')` is still running.

Comment: I doubt that `os.system('pipenv shell')` is doing anything useful here - the shell will close before you run the next command.

Comment: Thanks, Just noticed that now. How do I keep the shell open?

Comment: Use `pipenv run python manage.py runserver` instead

Comment: That works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older modules `os.system, os.spawn*` are replaced by newer module with more functionalities `subprocess` and is recommended to use instead of older ones.

Use `os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, 'python manage.py runserver')` which will return the PID of the new process without waiting for the return code.

`subprocess.Popen()` creates background child processes and does't wait to finish the child processes. For more please follow the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `subprocess`,

```
from subprocess import call
call('python manage.py runserver',shell=True,cwd="/my/code/dir/") # your code directory
webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8000', new=1, autoraise=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.Popen() worked for me as @arryph recommended.

Comment: Please try to avoid answers like "this worked for me too".